# Large Image View with Cut/Paste for Mac

Tags: macos, macbook

I am looking for an image view program for Mac that can handle large images. I used to use preview but, since "upgrading" to Mojave, preview will not display large

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Phiewer](https://phiewer.com) to try. Not sure how large an image it handles but it will open and display a 1920 x 1080 image ad I suppose larger. The basic version of the App is free so its at least worth a try. If you say how large an image you want to open I could give you another option if needed.

Comment: A large one I have is 132,518 x 12,000 pixels.

Comment: You may have to use Gimp on that image.  It is also a free app.  You can just google Gimp for Mac..

Comment: Sadly GIMP is very slow. When PREVIEW worked, I could open a large image in a couple of seconds and zoom with only a slight pause. GIMP takes minutes to load a large image. I don't think it's mac optimized to use its tiling features.

Comment: Ouch, you do have difficulties. Photoshop is my next suggestion but i know it is very expensive.  Are these images astronomical images? I would suggest looking for some astronomy image processing apps.  I'll look and see what I can find.

Comment: What image format are your files?

Comment: There is a site https://www.files-conversion.com/image/fits that will probably convert your image to the FITS format but it may take a while. But once in the FITS format you should be able to display it with "FITS Preview" from the App Store. FITS is an astronomical image format.